# Java thread wont synchronize

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I just started working with notify, synchronized and wait, and it almost works, but only when I let the second Thread sleep() for 1 ms. You can see my console output at the end.

My main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    InfoPaket paket = new InfoPaket();
    TestThread testThread = new TestThread(paket);
    TestThread2 testThread2 = new TestThread2(paket);
}
```

My "Lock" Class

```
public class InfoPaket {

String info;
char infoDataSign;
boolean newInfo = false;



public synchronized boolean isNew(){
    if (!newInfo){
        try {

            System.out.println("waiting");
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return newInfo;
}


public synchronized String getInfo() {
    newInfo = false;
    return info;
}
public synchronized void setInfo(String info) {this.info = info;
    newInfo = true;
    notify();
}
```

My two test Thread

1.

```
public class TestThread implements Runnable {

InfoPaket info;
int i = 0;

public TestThread(InfoPaket info)  {
    this.info = info;
    new Thread(this,"TestThread").start();
}   



public void run() {
    while(true){
        i++;
        getInfo();
    }
}



 void getInfo(){
     info.isNew();
     System.out.println("he got it... " + info.getInfo() + "  " + i);
    }
```

2.

```
public class TestThread2 implements Runnable{


InfoPaket info;
Thread t;
int i = 0;

public TestThread2(InfoPaket info)  {
    this.info = info;
    t = new Thread(this,"TestThread");
    t.start();
}   



public void run() {
    while(i < 500000){
        i++;
        setInfo();
    }
}



 void setInfo(){

     info.setInfo("lelaoao");
     System.out.println("here  " + i);

     try {
        t.sleep(1);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Here my results which are very clear and nice (except for the start):

```
waiting
he got it... lelaoao  1
waiting
here  1
here  2
he got it... lelaoao  2
waiting
here  3
he got it... lelaoao  3
waiting
here  4
he got it... lelaoao  4
waiting
here  5
he got it... lelaoao  5
waiting
here  6
he got it... lelaoao  6
```

And so on..

But putting the 2. thread everytime asleep slows down the program,
but without it I get something strange that I can't explain to myself:

```
waiting
here  1
he got it... lelaoao  1
he got it... lelaoao  2
waiting
here  2
here  3
he got it... lelaoao  3
he got it... lelaoao  4
waiting
here  4
here  5
here  6
here  7
here  8
here  9
here  10
he got it... lelaoao  5
he got it... lelaoao  6
waiting
```

Comment: "But puting the 2. thread evertime asleep slows down the programm. but without i get something crazy i cant explain to myself"..??

Comment: Threads are expected to be well-behaved. thread 1 does not sleep and does not wait because get info method does not wait either, so you have the makings of a runaway thread. The time savings of threading have to be greater than the costs associated with synchronization

Comment: @RajeevRanjan better? =)

Comment: @efekctive what is a runway thread? and why doesnt it wait? becouse it prints "waiting"?

Comment: Look at thread 1. The loop does not sleep. It calls getInfo which does only one thing: getting new Info. When Thread 2 sleeps thread 1 can execute several hundred times in one millisecond. If this helped you I will post it as an answer

Comment: but the method getInfo() doeas include a wait() methode.

Comment: and its thread 2 which  executes so often

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. Let me look at this again

Comment: I can't debug this now but I would follow the good-behavior rule. Threading have a cost so mind the synchronization costs. The work your methods do not overcome the synchronization hurdle hence slows down. You could use sleep(0, XX nanos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is working as expected (as coded), except - 1) You have some bad code 2) You may have misunderstood the concept.

Let me first start by saying what your code is doing:

1. You have a `InfoPaket` which is shared among your 2 thread and hold info about packet, and keeps track whether new info is received or not.
2. Then your have `TestThread` which will check if new info is received or not, if new info is not recieved then it will wait and once new info is received then you will print the info (which is always "lelaoao") along with your loop counter, like this `he got it... lelaoao  23`
3. Then your have `TestThread2` which will set the info and notify the waiting thread and then print the loop counter of this thread like this - `"here  " + i`.

Now, most important thing for your understand is that thread scheduling is unexpected and depends on underlying OS thread scheduling mechanism as well as JVM implementation, so you cannot expect that if thread 2 has set info then then certainly thread 1 will execute, you can **try to** enforce it putting `Thread.sleep(1)` or `Thread.yeild()`, **please note that `Thread.yeild()` is not portable** and it is good that you are not using it and should not be use it, instead of it you should use `Thread.sleep(1)`

Now let come to bad code and some important concepts:

## Bad code

1. The most wrong thing you were doing is you were starting a new thread from the constructor, **don't ever try to start a new thread from the constructor** because it will cause your reference to leak even before your constructor has completed. Read [this excellent article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0618/index.html).
2. You don't need a reference of current thread in `TestThread2` because you can directly do `Thread.sleep(1);` which will cause current thread to sleep.
3. You were printing `System.out.println("he got it... " + info + "  " + i);` and `System.out.println("here  " + i);` from your main thread, however you should print these from synchronized block to ensure that there is no interleaving, because **in absence of synchronization interleaving could occur** and you could see `he got it... lelaoao  3` before `here  3` which is logically wrong.

Now, below is the fixed code which will consistent produce correct result (*considering your are giving thread 1 chance to run once thread 2 has set info*), output is also placed in the end.

**InfoPaket.java**

```
public class InfoPaket {

    String info;
    char infoDataSign;
    boolean newInfo = false;

    public synchronized boolean isNew() {
        if (!newInfo) {
            try {
                System.out.println("waiting");
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return newInfo;
    }

    public synchronized void getInfo(int i) {
        newInfo = false;
        System.out.println("he got it... " + info + "  " + i);
    }

    public synchronized void setInfo(String info, int i) {
        this.info = info;
        newInfo = true;
        System.out.println("here  " + i);
        notify();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        InfoPaket paket = new InfoPaket();
        TestThread testThread = new TestThread(paket);
        TestThread2 testThread2 = new TestThread2(paket);

        new Thread(testThread, "testThread").start();
        new Thread(testThread2, "testThread2").start();
    }
}
```

**TestThread.java**

```
public class TestThread implements Runnable {

    InfoPaket info;
    int i = 0;

    public TestThread(InfoPaket info) {
        this.info = info;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            i++;
            getInfo(i);
        }
    }

    void getInfo(int i2){
         info.isNew();
         info.getInfo(i2);
    }
}
```

**TestThread2.java**

```
public class TestThread2 implements Runnable {

    InfoPaket info;
    int i = 0;

    public TestThread2(InfoPaket info) {
        this.info = info;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (i < 500000) {
            i++;
            setInfo(i);
        }
    }

    void setInfo(int i2) {

        info.setInfo("lelaoao", i2);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
waiting
here  1
he got it... lelaoao  1
waiting
here  2
he got it... lelaoao  2
waiting
here  3
he got it... lelaoao  3
waiting
here  4
he got it... lelaoao  4
waiting
here  5
he got it... lelaoao  5
waiting
here  6
he got it... lelaoao  6
waiting
here  7
he got it... lelaoao  7
waiting
here  8
he got it... lelaoao  8
waiting
here  9
he got it... lelaoao  9
waiting
here  10
he got it... lelaoao  10
waiting
here  11
he got it... lelaoao  11
waiting
here  12
he got it... lelaoao  12
waiting
here  13
he got it... lelaoao  13
waiting
here  14
he got it... lelaoao  14
waiting
here  15
he got it... lelaoao  15
waiting
here  16
he got it... lelaoao  16
waiting
here  17
he got it... lelaoao  17
waiting
here  18
he got it... lelaoao  18
waiting
here  19
he got it... lelaoao  19
waiting
here  20
he got it... lelaoao  20
waiting
here  21
he got it... lelaoao  21
waiting
here  22
he got it... lelaoao  22
waiting
here  23
he got it... lelaoao  23
waiting
here  24
he got it... lelaoao  24
waiting
here  25
he got it... lelaoao  25
waiting
here  26
he got it... lelaoao  26
waiting
here  27
he got it... lelaoao  27
waiting
here  28
he got it... lelaoao  28
waiting
here  29
he got it... lelaoao  29
waiting
here  30
he got it... lelaoao  30
waiting
here  31
he got it... lelaoao  31
```

## Important concepts to be clear about

I think you might be missing some concept so you are thinking output to be crazy.

1. Once you have set the info using thread 2 there is no guarantee that thread 1 will run because thread scheduling is unexpected and depends on underlying OS thread scheduling mechanism as well as JVM implementation, I have highlighted more point about this in the start with `Thread.yield()` and `Thread.sleep()`. With that note, if you don't use `Thread.sleep(1)` then you just can't expect output to be consistent, as I have shown below.
2. When you do `Thread.sleep` then it doesn't release the lock, if that thread is acquiring some lock.
3. Once you do `notify();` then you can't expect the waiting thread to be "runnable" immediately and the thread which is acquiring the lock will not release immediately release the lock as soon as `notify();` is called, lock will be released only once that synchronized block/method is finished.
4. If you don't do `Thread.sleep(1)` in your 2nd thread then you can't expect the consistent output, and reasons I have explained above.

---

OP's comment:

> Do you know any a more efficent way of transmitting data from on
>   thread to an other one?

Either you have "**shared memory**" or "**message passing**"; shared memory is what we are doing in this case, and if you want to go for message passing then you can go for Java API like blocking queue (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) implementation, but that's becomes all together different story.

Comment: Thank you very much for your code and your explanation =)

Comment: You haven't identified everything wrong in the OP's code. Sleeping shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Do you know any a more efficent way of transmitting data from on thread to an other one?

Comment: @NathanHughes Sleeping (1 milisecond) gives a chance to thread1 to run, in absence of `Thread.sleep(1)` it would totally un-deterministic that whether t1 or t2 would run, with  `Thread.sleep(1)` on t2 mostly t1 will run, other way used to be `Thread.yield` but it is not portable and I have mentioned the same in my answer.

Comment: would sleep(0) work aswell?  becouse it should do the same thing as yield?

Comment: @Olgidos No, it would not do anything.

Comment: @Olgidos Join has altogether a different purpose, I don't think you need join here, join allows 2 threads to join so that thread 1 will wait for thread 2 to complete, you can read more on this in this excellent Oracle tutorial - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html ...